# Error notebook samsung np300e4c Boot menu is empty

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios, hardware-failure

I have my notebook Samsung NP300e4c. When turned on yesterday it shows me a picture with the list of boot options menu and app, but the list of boot I get empty !!!!

[image]

Entering BIOS recognizes my device but the boot priority list does not show me anything.

[image]

What to do please I need your help. and replace disk and restart the BIOS

EDIT [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PbWR.jpg) 29/10/2014

This image shows the BIOS correctly recognizes the hardware connected to the sata ports, so connectivity issues not think it

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, I bought a new hard drive, because the former was dead. 
I changed the hard drive in the notebook and still continues with the startup list empty

Comment: Please be precise when you are writing questions. Currently I guess you can hear the hard drive spinning. Still sounds like a hardware issue : are you sure you plugged it correctly? It would be relevant if you upload pictures from inside you notebook to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated the post with a picture but the bios shows the peripherals are connected correctly.

Comment: Then, can you try to boot on the CD-ROM or Hard Drive *(if you installed an OS on it)* again.

Comment: Thanks, but as I show in the pictures the hardware is recognized by BIOS but not the boot order, I tried to boot from a CD but there all the time if I get the first image

Answer (score 1):

I was searching months for a decent solution for this problem with same NP Samsung model. There are an incredible key-combination to boot from DVD-ROM and finally to get access.

First thing is to reset bios configuration with RTC BIOS pins, located besides RAM slots (alternatively, you can remove the CMOS battery for a moment). Then, insert a bootable USB drive or DVD-ROM and automatically press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (for DVD boot) or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (for USB boot).

If that doesn't work, try with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keys. If you have any OS installed on your HDD this will make it start.

I know, is not *the* solution for this problem, but an alternative to "jump it". Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

was searching months for a decent solution for this problem with same NP Samsung model. There are an incredible key-combination to boot from DVD-ROM and finally to get access.

First thing is to reset bios configuration with RTC BIOS pins, located besides RAM slots (alternatively, you can remove the CMOS battery for a moment). Then, insert a bootable USB drive or DVD-ROM and automatically press Fn+F3 (for DVD boot) or Fn+F5 (for USB boot).

If that doesn't work, try with Ctrl+F keys. If you have any OS installed on your HDD this will make it start.

I know, is not the solution for this problem, but an alternative to "jump it". Hope it works for you!